# Lucene.net Umbraco order by multiple fields

Tags: c#, umbraco, lucene.net

I am trying to search on multiple fields in Umbraco and order the results by two factors:

1. Is it a specific type, yes place it on top
2. Order it by stock

I am using Umbraco 4.9.1.

```
var Searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["MySearcher"];
var searchCriteria = Searcher.CreateSearchCriteria();
var results = Searcher.Search(searchCriteria.OrderByDescending("IsAccesoires", "stock").Compile().RawQuery(search));
```

If I only search on IsAccesoires it works; if I search on both (IsAccesoires and stock") stock ignores the IsAccesoires.

Comment: Seems like stock is a string and doesn't order the correct way. In my index i said it has been set to a Integer and 'orderable'.